# What is the performance impact of virtual memory relative to direct mapped memory?

Tags: performance, memory, memory-management

[Virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) is a convenient way to isolate memory among processes and give each process its own address space. It works by translating virtual addresses to physical addresses.

I'm already very familiar with how virtual memory works and is implemented. What I don't know about is the performance impact of virtual memory relative to direct mapped memory, which requires no overhead for translation.

Please don't say that there is no overhead. This is obviously false since traversing page tables requires several memory accesses. It is possible that TLB misses are infrequent enough that the performance impacts are negligible, however, if this is the case there should be evidence for it.

I also realize the importance of virtual memory for many of the functions a modern OS provides, so this question isn't about whether virtual memory is good or bad (it is clearly a good thing for most use cases), I'm asking purely about the performance effects of virtual memory.

The answer I'm looking for is ideally something like: virtual memory imposes an x% overhead over direct mapping and here is a paper showing that. I tried to look for papers with such results, but was unable to find any.

Comment: The problem with your question is that any such overhead is non-linear and would depend upon usage. In addition, it depends upon the type of VM implementation. Are you talking just about logical memory translation or full virtual memory overhead? VM started in the 1970's and had taken over for multi-user systems by the 1980s. So the overhead is low enough that  no one cases about it.

Comment: The Mill CPU uses only a single, global address space, which is big enough at 64 bits: http://millcomputing.com/topic/memory/  Still does memory protection between processes, but no virtual address mapping required.

Comment: @user3344003 I mostly meant virtual to physical address translation, since it seems to me that is where most of the costs would come in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question is difficult to answer definitively because virtual memory is an integral part of modern systems are designed to support virtual memory and most software is written and optimized using systems with virtual memory.

However, in the early 2000s Microsoft Research developed a research OS called [Signularity](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/singularity/) that, among other things, did not rely on virtual memory for process isolation.  As part of this project they published a paper where they analyzed the overhead of hardware support for process isolation.  The paper is entitled [Deconstructing Process Isolation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?doid=1178597.1178599) (non-paywall link [here](http://research.cs.wisc.edu/areas/os/Seminar/schedules/papers/Deconstructing_Process_Isolation_final.pdf)).  In the paper the researchers write:

> Most operating systems use a CPU’s memory management hardware to
>   provide process isolation, using two mechanisms. First, processes are
>   only allowed access to certain pages of physical memory. Second,
>   privilege levels prevent untrusted code from manipulating the system
>   resources that implement processes, for example, the memory management
>   unit (MMU) or interrupt controllers. These mechanisms’ non-trivial
>   performance costs are largely hidden, since there is no widely used
>   alternative approach to compare them to. Mapping from virtual to
>   physical addresses can incur overheads up to 10–30% due to exception
>   handling, inline TLB lookup, TLB reloads, and maintenance of kernel
>   data structures such as page tables [29]. In addition, virtual memory
>   and privilege levels increase the cost of inter-process communication.

Later in the paper they write:

> Virtual memory systems (with the exception of software-only systems
>   such as SPUR [46]) rely on a hardware cache of address translations to
>   avoid accessing page tables at every processor cache miss. Managing
>   TLB entries has a cost, which Jacob and Mudge estimated at 5–10% on a
>   simulated MIPS-like processor [29]. The virtual memory system also
>   brings its data, and in some systems, code as well, into a processor’s
>   caches, which evicts user code and data. Jacob and Mudge estimate
>   that, with small caches, these induced misses can increase the
>   overhead to 10–20%. Furthermore, they found that virtual memory
>   induced interrupts can increase the overhead to 10–30%. Other studies
>   found similar or even higher overheads, though the actual costs are
>   very dependent on system details and benchmarks [3, 6, 10, 26, 36, 40,
>   41]. In addition, TLB access is on the critical path of many processor
>   designs [2, 30] and so might affect processor clock speed.

Overall I would take these results with a grain of salt since the research is promoting an alternative system.  But clearly there is some overhead associated with implementing virtual memory, and this paper gives one attempt to quantify some of these overheads (within the context of evaluating a possible alternative).  I recommend reading the paper for more detail.

Comment: Thanks, something like this was exactly what I was looking for. I was familiar with Singularity, but had never seen that paper. Thanks! Also, if you haven't seen it, one of the developers of Midori (Singularity's successor) has a great series of blog posts where he talks about the designing Midori. It's really interesting stuff. Here's the link: http://joeduffyblog.com/2015/11/03/blogging-about-midori/